# Android: How can i download a file from a URL to asset folder of the app?

Tags: android, mobile

When I start running the app in the mobile, it must connect to a URL and download dataset(files) to the app folder of the app..Is this possible? if so please could you show me a sample ?

Comment: I am not sure that you can download in assets folder because this folder is bundled with the apk hence you cant change the content of this folder same like "res".

but you can always save the data in the internal app directory. using File mFile = new File(mActivity.getFilesDir(), "file.txt");

Comment: Thank you mudit.The internal app directory you talking about, is it a private directory accessible only by the app?

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 4):

you cannot download files in app's Asset folder. Instead you should use `getCacheDir()` (on internal memory) or `getExternalCacheDir()` (on SD card, available in Froyo and above) to download and retrieve your files.

Comment: Thank you waqas.. will check on getCacheDir()..tht ll help me i guess

Comment: getCacheDir is good way but it is not safe if you are saving user settings or some useful information there. As user can delete this data from the settings app using --Applications > manage Applications > your app > "Clear data"

Comment: you cannot control this behavior. Let the users have full control of their device. They can clear cache/data, but your app should be flexible enough to detect the missing data and download it again

Answer (score 1):

All the details are available here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

`File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "sample.jpg");`

use this to get an internal app private directory. You can use debug feature to actually see what is the directory it is referring.

Answer (score 0):

check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76208291/10784151

```
step 1: add the plugin
//compile time download
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'


Step2: Download a multiple file to a directory, during compile time

task downloadFile(type: Download) {
    src 'https://www.url.com/base_theme.json' //file url
    dest 'src/main/assets' //file destination
    overwrite true

    src 'https://www.url.com/theme_mso.json'
    dest 'src/main/assets'
    overwrite true
}
preBuild.dependsOn downloadFile
```