# Android+Gradle download a file on build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to download a file before the build and place it in my local "assets" folder.

I found this but I'm not familiar enough with gradle to use it in an android project.

https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task

I have the "android" task of course, but can I say this file downloading task should be done before that task?

Part of my build file:

```
android {
...
download {
        src 'https://example.com/data.json'
        dest assets
    }
...
}
```

This builds but nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

From the link you have provided, after configuring the plugin, write this task outside the **android closure**

```
task myTask << {
    //do something ...
    //... then download a file
    download {
        src 'http://www.example.com/index.html' // replace with your link
        dest buildDir // replace it with assets directory path
    }
    //... do something else
}
```

Add this line to run it before build

```
preBuild.dependsOn(mytask)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make the changes according to this sample code give

**First make changes to project level gradle file like ,**

https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/blob/master/build.gradle

**Next go to your main module build.gradle**

[Sample Download Task From The Same source](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/blob/master/examples/simpleTask.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

```
        step 1: add the plugin
//compile time download
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'


Step2: Download a multiple file to a directory, during compile time

task downloadFile(type: Download) {
    src 'https://www.url.com/base_theme.json' //file url
    dest 'src/main/assets' //file destination
    overwrite true

    src 'https://www.url.com/theme_mso.json'
    dest 'src/main/assets'
    overwrite true
}
preBuild.dependsOn downloadFile
```